# How can we build KAA source code in Eclipse

Tags: kaa

Can any one from KAA team guide us on how to build the kaa source code in Eclipse IDE. or else provide a required information to build the kaa source code in other then the eclipse IDE.

Note: If possible, please provide the list of external software or IDE settings  required to installed/Configured to successfully build the code.

Comment: Are you trying to build the server part or one of the Kaa SDKs?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to compile the whole source code available on github. But Yes, i am interested in Server part. So please guide me which folder(s) should i include in eclipse if i want to compile the Server part?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a folder called server which has all Java classes of the server side application, Basically Kaa project is a maven java project you can import the project to your eclipse the same way you would import any maven project to eclipse just click File->Import->Maven then browse to your project.

On other hand you can compile the project from your terminal if you already have maven installed on your system, by running this command from within the project folder

```
mvn -P compile-gwt,mongo-dao,mariadb-dao clean install verify
```

Comment: Thanks mohamed, i will try your suggestion and let you update.